# Google Calendar Invites Replacing Outlook Email with Gmail Address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, gmail, google-calendar

We're experiencing a rather weird issue where a Google Calendar Invitation meant for a Outlook email address is being sent to a Gmail address instead. We originally thought that this could be a forwarding rule setup in Outlook but there are no rules setup. Furthermore the Google Calendar invite isn't showing up in an email trace meaning that it's not even hitting the Outlook servers. The email appears to be kept in the Google ecosystem and as if Google is replacing the Outlook email with a Gmail address. Is there some kind of setting within Google/Gmail that would cause this type of behavior?

Comment: What makes you think Google Calendar doesn’t support Outlook meeting invites?

Comment: What are you talking about? I'm talking about Google Calendar invites being redirected to a gmail account rather than the intended Outlook email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that invites sent to outlook account started being redirected to Gmail account?
I found a similar [thread](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/calendar-invitations-sent-to-my-o365-email-address-go-to-gmail/m-p/1304727),

> I discovered that my private gmail account had here: https://myaccount.google.com/email a list of alternate emails for me. One of them was my pro O365 email.

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thank you this did end up fixing the issue! We thought it might be this but our testing didn't yield the same behavior as the user was experiencing.